# Laravel - 403 redirect. Redirect is correct working for tags and category sections but not for users

Tags: laravel, redirect, blogs

I'm trying to set the post admin section. The mission for that section is to show all articles that belong to logged user. The way I'm doing for tags and categories is working correct (tags and categories doesn't need to be filtered for any user). The post page works correctly show the owned post for logged user, but the problem is that the user can't edit or show any post and trying to store a new post redirects to 403 page. I'm confuse by the error and I don't have any solution. I appreciate some help.

PostModel

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'category_id', 'name', 'slug', 'excerpt', 'body', 'status', 'file'
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
    }
    
}
```

PostController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Tag;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests\PostStoreRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\PostUpdateRequest;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->paginate();

        return view('admin.posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $categories = Category::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->pluck('name', 'id');
        $tags       = Tag::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();

        return view('admin.posts.create', compact('categories', 'tags'));
    }

    public function store(PostStoreRequest $request)
    {
        $post = Post::create($request->all());
        $this->authorize('pass', $post);

        //IMAGE 
        if($request->file('image')){
            $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('image',  $request->file('image'));
            $post->fill(['file' => asset($path)])->save();
        }

        //TAGS
        $post->tags()->attach($request->get('tags'));

        return redirect()->route('posts.edit', $post->id)->with('info', 'Success');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $this->authorize('pass', $post);

        return view('admin.posts.show', compact('post'));
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $categories = Category::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->pluck('name', 'id');
        $tags       = Tag::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
        $post       = Post::find($id);
        $this->authorize('pass', $post);
        
        return view('admin.posts.edit', compact('post', 'categories', 'tags'));
    }

    public function update(PostUpdateRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $this->authorize('pass', $post);

        $post->fill($request->all())->save();

        //IMAGE 
        if($request->file('image')){
            $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('image',  $request->file('image'));
            $post->fill(['file' => asset($path)])->save();
        }

        //TAGS
        $post->tags()->sync($request->get('tags'));

        return redirect()->route('posts.edit', $post->id)->with('info', 'Success');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id)->delete();
        $this->authorize('pass', $post);

        return back()->with('info', 'Deleted');
    }
}
```

PostUpdateRequest

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class PostUpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'name'          => 'required',
            'slug'          => 'required|unique:posts,slug,' . $this->post,
            'user_id'       => 'required|integer',
            'category_id'   => 'required|integer',
            'tags'          => 'required|array',
            'body'          => 'required',
            'status'        => 'required|in:DRAFT,PUBLISHED',
        ];

        if($this->get('image'))        
            $rules = array_merge($rules, ['image'         => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png']);

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

PostStoreRequest

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class PostStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'name'          => 'required',
            'slug'          => 'required|unique:posts,slug',
            'user_id'       => 'required|integer',
            'category_id'   => 'required|integer',
            'tags'          => 'required|array',
            'body'          => 'required',
            'status'        => 'required|in:DRAFT,PUBLISHED',            
        ];

        if($this->get('image'))        
            $rules = array_merge($rules, ['image'         => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png']);

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

And for example, the post.edit

```
@extends('admin.admin')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                   {{ __('Editar artículo') }}
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">
                   {!! Form::model($post, ['route' => ['posts.update', $post->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
                     @include('admin.posts.partials.form')
                   {!! Form::close() !!} 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

And finally the form

```
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::hidden('user_id', auth()->user()->id) }}
</div> 
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('category_id', 'Category') }}
    {{ Form::select('category_id', $categories, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</div> 
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('name', 'Tag name') }}
    {{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('slug', 'URL friendly') }}
    {{ Form::text('slug', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'slug']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('image', 'Image') }}
    {{ Form::file('image') }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('slug', 'State') }}
    <label>
        {{ Form::radio('status', 'PUBLISHED') }} Published
    </label>
    <label>
        {{ Form::radio('status', 'DRAFT') }} Draft
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('tags', 'Tags') }}
    <div>
    @foreach($tags as $tag)
        <label>
            {{ Form::checkbox('tags[]', $tag->id) }} {{ $tag->name }}
        </label>
    @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('excerpt', 'Excerpt') }}
    {{ Form::textarea('excerpt', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '2']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('body', 'Description') }}
    {{ Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::submit('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary']) }}
</div>

@section('scripts')
<script src="{{ asset('components/stringToSlug/jquery.stringToSlug.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#name, #slug").stringToSlug({
            callback: function(text){
                $('#slug').val(text);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

Sorry for the extension but it was necessary to explain the problem.

Comment: Have you defined PostPolicy? Controller method's `$this->authorize('pass', $post)` expects a PostPolicy if it can't find the Policy class it will throw unauthorized exception which results in 403 redirect

Comment: @Donkarnash there was the code error. Congratss your acuity. +10. Im sorry for my english.

Comment: Also no need to duplicate authorization. If you are doing it in FormRequest i.e PostRequest then there's no need to authorize in the controller method again

Comment: Thanks. I don't have FormRequest file. Its just for Post, Category and Tag,

Comment: What I meant was that you are using PostStoreRequest and PostUpdateRequest which already have `authorize()` method you don't need to duplicate `$this->authorize()` in store and update method of the controller

Comment: If absence of PostPolicy was the reason for the 403 redirect error - I need to put it as an answer for the benefit of subsequent visitors - let me know

Comment: Yes It was the error. You solved the problem. I completed the PostPolicy file, and the authorize() method was deleted from controllers. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The authorize() method in controller method looks for a corresponding policy. If Laravel can't find the corresponding policy it throws unauthenticated exception.

So in this case `$this->authorize('pass', $post)`, expects to find a `PostPolicy` class, otherwise it will throw unauthorized exception which is converted to 403 redirect by middleware.

Read more about Policies https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#creating-policies.

Note: When using FormRequest to handle validation, authorization can be done in FormRequest and there's not need to duplicate authorization in controller method